# How can I create executable package for OneGet Install-Package?

Tags: powershell, nuget, .net-core, oneget

I understand how to create a package for NuGet. There's also nothing especially hard with creating a NuGet package or PowerShell package.

I'm aware it may be impossible to create PowerShell package with binary cmdlet in .NET Core, so wondering if it's possible to create a package with lifecycle hooks.

Say, in `npm`, you can define [scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#description) in `package.json` to declare pre/post install/publish dependencies.

So, the question is:

How can I perform custom script after having my package added to the system via `Install-Package`?

For example, I want to add executable to PATH (likely to be pretty common task)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely, this one will work:
[project.json#scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json#scripts)
Note, that valid values are allowed platform executables, so, as I got that, PowerShell is not allowed by default.

Quick workaround, as far as arguments are available:

`runner.cmd`:

```
@powershell -File %1
```

and in `project.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "postrestore": "%project:Directory%/scripts/runner.cmd %project:Directory%/scripts/install.ps1"
}
```